# Is it "I'm glad to tell you" or "I'm glad I can tell you"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is right?

1. I am glad to tell you that ...
2. I am glad I can tell you that ...

Or can both be used?

I am from Germany and we use both (in German).

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, they obey all the grammar rules, and are reasonably idiomatic. The meanings might be subtly different, as the second one has the word "can" - which links to "ability" or "permission", and suggests that previously "I  couldn't tell you."

Comment: Also often seen is 'I am glad to be able to tell you...'